# How to a use android debug bridge on my frozen phone without usb debugging

Tags: adb, recovery-mode

My AZUMI IRO A4Q crashed. I tried to access the recovery menu  using the volume up/down/power button combinations but non of them work. It goes directly to the Digicel screen and freezes there. Is there anyway to access the recovery menu using adb without USB debugging, which I didn't enable prior to the crash?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.hardreset99.com/azumi-mobile/azumi-iro-a4q-hard-reset/) site mentions this procedure for getting into recovery:

- Volume Up + Power button (or)
- Home button + Volume Up + Power button(or)
- Volume Down + Power button (or)
- Volume Up + Volume Down + Power button

Once you get into recovery, you should be able to use ADB in I remeber correctly, and if not you can easily factory reset

Comment: I've accessed the recovery menu but factory reset doesn't work